# WORKDIR followed by ENTRYPOINT script versus executing script in container

Tags: docker

Should not a Docker file with

```
WORKDIR /bin
ENTRYPOINT /bin/some_script.sh
```

as the last part do same as `docker exec` into container moving to /bin/ inside and then
run some_script.sh explicitly ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, WORKDIR sets the working directory for the image, and the next CMD or ENTRYPOINT is launched using this default directory. What is your point ?

Comment: In script I start TomEE server with app. If using Dockerfile without last 2 line and startup TomEE from inside container it works, but with WORKDIR and ENTRYPOINT above to do automatically, app does not work due to problems with using database.

Answer (score 0):

Does your script return (exit) right after it is started?

If this happens, then your docker container stops too.
Starting the script in an interactive mode will work though.

Please add a sleep 1000 as the last line of /bin/some_script.sh and check if the container starts correctly (at least for 1000 seconds).

If this works, try to change your script so that your application runs in foreground without returning before tomee stops itself.